# Why HttpClient is not opening any page in the browser?

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I have a console application and I want to open a asp.net page from it.

I tried this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
client.GetAsync("http://localhost:9000/");
```

but when I run the application, nothing in the browser becomes opened.

Comment: You missed the documentation for HttpClient.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Please use/ read: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: @Dan-o i already tried to read and I found out that I need to use the `GetAsync` but it seems that I was mistaken.

Comment: why not `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost:9000/");` ?

Comment: Your mistake is not in the use of the `GetAsync` method.  It is in the use of the `HttpClient` class.  `HttpClient` does not have a graphical component, nor does it control a web browser.

Comment: @decoherence your solution was the good one. write an answer to accept it please

Comment: @decoherence please write your answer to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to open the page in your default browser, you could use

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost:9000/");
```

As mentioned in the comments by Dano-o
"`HttpClient` does not have a graphical component, nor does it control a web browser."

Answer (score 3):

you use `HttpClient` when you want to get or post data programmaticaly. If you want to open an external application in your operating system you should use [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Just start it with the url you want and your operating system will open the default browser for you.

Like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost:9000/")
```

Comment: plus one for u but there is another user who told me this solution before, i am waiting for him/her to write his/her answer